# Rename text anchor and update cross-reference text

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have quite a few text anchors in a document and now the naming of the text anchors has to be changed.

1. Does someone know how to rename text anchors (have not found a rename option yet)
2. Is it then sufficient to just select refresh in the cross-references panel to get the texts updated?

**EDIT:**

Found something similar!? One has to know that *Text anchors* are grouped as Hyperlinks. You can rename them in the *Hyperlink panel* or *Cross-References panel* under *Hyperlink Destination Option*.

The catch is - after a rename and refresh, they point to the beginning of the document. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Merged new findings into topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this easily from within InDesign, but there is a simple workaround:

- Export the InDesign file to IDML, which is simply an XML file where everything is in plain text.
- Load the file into a good text editor, and run Search/Replace on the terms you need to change.
- Open the updated IDML file in InDesign, which will give you a fresh InDesign file with the renamed anchors.

A bonus with this approach is that it will clear out any clutter that may have accumulated in the file while you were editing it, giving you a completely "clean" INDD.

Comment: Alan, are you sure that IDML files are XML? InDesign CS6, it seems that the file is binary.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name from within Indesign. Click on the Hyperlink Destination options in the flyout menu of the Hyperlinks panel. Select your destination and click Edit.
[image]

Uncheck the Set to current text insertion point checkbox.

Comment: This works for me, but there are 2 drawbacks. The first drawback is that to make the "Update cross-references" button clickable, you need edit the cross-reference itself: it doesn't matter how. The second issue is that if you have multiple cross-references to that anchor, you will need to repeat the first step step for each of them.